How to access files under "Files > Browse > On My iPhone" using libimobiledevice utilities on a non-jailbroken iPhone?
I'm using the libimobiledevice utilities to access files on a non-jailbroken iPhone. Specifically, I want to access files located under Files > Browse > On My iPhone.
So far, I can successfully access files within specific app directories using the command
ifuse MOUNTPOINT --documents APPID.
However, I am unable to access files that are directly in On My iPhone (i.e., not inside a folder).
Is it possible to access these files on a non-jailbroken iPhone using libimobiledevice? If so, what is the correct approach or command?
